# How do I make a passive sentence with "be believed"?

Tags: verbs, passive-voice, auxiliary-verbs

I need to make a new sentence with the verb in brackets:

> Many bacteria are resistant to antibiotics. (to be believed).

I thought it could be

> Many bacteria **believed to be** resistant to antibiotics.

but it sounds weird to me, because how can bacteria believe anything? How can I rephrase the part in bold to make the sentence grammatical?

Comment: Many bacteria **are** believed to be [something].

Comment: Please write the answers in answer block provided and not in comments

Comment: You write it if you want to.

Comment: Answers to low quality questions like this one (count the close votes) attract downvotes. Comments don't.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey that is not a good reason for abusing the intended design of the SE system.  (Also, in my experience, your assertion not generally true in the ELL SE anyway)

Answer (score 2):

Passive verbs in English are **always** formed using the appropriate form of the verb "be" and a perfect participle.

> The wine was drunk by my guests before I even arrived.

"Was" is a form of the verb "be" and "drunk" is the perfect participle of "drink."

Sometimes the form of the verb "be" is itself in the form of a participle plus an auxiliary.

> The wine was being drunk rapidly when I arrived.
>
> The wine should have been drunk after I arrived.